# What is the name of the "[ ]" functionality that can be added to a wordpress blog or page?

Tags: php, wordpress

Please feel free to format the question title.

I have been coding a few plugins, and I want a plugin that I can call directly from a page or blog post.

I have seen lots of plugins implement a "[]" on the page/blog editor and I am trying to replicate that behavior.

For example: I want the functionality to write a blogpost, and call this function that echos "Hello world!".

---

```
Hello this is a page. [hello]
```

---

And the output would be:

---

Hello this is a page. Hello world!

---

What is this functionality called and if I could get an example on how to code it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

shortcode

Here's the docs:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API

Simplest form is:

```
function foobar_func( $atts ){
 return "foo and bar";
}
add_shortcode( 'foobar', 'foobar_func' );
```

Then calling `[foobar]` in any post / page, will call the defined function `foobar_func`.